# add login menu with submenu

Tags: menus

I need to add "Login" to main nav-menu. with sub menu "register" (link `http://www.vcanade.ca/register/`)

After user logged in, "Login" has to change to his username with sub menus "profile" (link `http://www.vcanade.ca/your-profile/`) and "Logout"

Is there way to do this?

So far I did only to display logged in user name by adding to fuction.php

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {  
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if(!empty($current_user->user_login))
        $items .= '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">'.$current_user->user_login.'</a></li>';        
    return $items;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a barebones example (which I just tested on my site):

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'asv_add_usermenu', 10, 2 );

function asv_add_usermenu( $items, $args ) {
  if (is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary-menu') {
    $items .= "<li class='sub-menu'><a href='" . wp_logout_url()  . "'>Log Out</a></li>";
  } elseif (!is_user_logged_in() && $args->theme_location == 'primary-menu') {
    $items .= "<li class='sub-menu'> <a href='" . wp_login_url() . "'>Log In</a></li>";
  }
  return $items;
}
```

The 'primary-menu' text is from this admin page (whatever name the theme registered that menu as). yoursite.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php It is one of the menu names in grey italics in the top left box.

I gleaned the above from [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items](http://wordpressgeekhelp.blogspot.com/2015/08/function-referencewp-get-nav-menu-items.html)
and codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu
and I think the 'primary-menu' is the only thing environment specific.

Comment: Thanks a lot. i did everything according you instruction, but new item menu does not appear in my menu at all.   'primary-menu' i changed to 'menu1' Any idea?